# Openfire xmpp scalability (1M to 10M Users)

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, hazelcast

I'm working on a large scale mobile chat app similar to Whatsapp and I have following questions:

1- I'm just wondering if Openfire is capable of handeling 1 to 10M users or not?

2- On average how many users each node can handle and what specification is required (RAM, CPU, etc)?

3- With hazelcast clustring how many nodes can we have?

Looking forward to hearing form experts here.

Cheers

Comment: Can you share your experience? Do you have any statistical output about openfire scalability?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question yes, there are universities that use OF, they can handle that traffic...dare to dream big.

Comment: Do you have more info? Like what specifications is required for servers (RAM, CPU, etc)?